# What does someone in HR think about websites made with the obvious intent to shame an applicant?

Tags: human-resources

My friend is applying for jobs. However, he has websites that have been made about him calling him some very unpleasant things... His crazy ex made these websites. They include his picture and her detailing what he did to her. He's tried to get them taken down however he can't. They link him to his linkedin and she states what university he comes from, etc.,

Anyways, he is applying for jobs and wants to know how badly this will damage his chances? He wants to work in finance as a trader. Is this bad enough? And do employers in this field even google their employees?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, if these are untrue/unfounded accusations, he should have a case for libel against his ex.  A cease and desist letter from a lawyer can go a long way...

These days employers definitely search out employees social presence.  Is this page like the top google result for his name, or in the 3rd page of results?  It's doubtful a potential employer is going to search but a few minutes on a candidate, at least for that first interview.  If HR does find it, it definitely could spell bad news, whether they believe it or not.  Likely they'll just move along to the next candidate and avoid the drama.

Comment: she made these websites anonymously. He hiired a PI on her but they couldn't find anything to link her to it. So theres no substantial case against her. So the websites have to stay up for now.

Comment: it's definitely on the first page of search results for his name

Comment: Getting way off topic here, but fire off a C&D to the hosting company.

Comment: It's remarkably difficult to build an entire website anonomously. I strongly suspect there's evidence of the site's creator.

Comment: also - at least in Europe - you could demand google not showing it in the search-results. (right to be forgotten)

Comment: libel cases require proving damages, something i don't think is realistic at this point.

Comment: @dandavis he claims he's having difficulty finding a job, damage to one's professional reputation can be considered. We also have no idea if there are other factors such as emotional distress.

Comment: @dandavis - There is such a thing as "presumed damages" in many courts.  This is why your friend should at least consult an attorney.  The "iANAL, but ..." app is not sufficient, here.

Comment: but my question is just, how would HR view this... I'm not talking about what he should do to remove it